# unsupported operand type(s) exception with ThreapPool.map but not map?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

Why does the built in map work but not multiprocessing's ThreadPool map work?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def identity(a, b): return (a, b)

map(identity, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])

p = ThreadPool(2)

#gives above error:
p.map(identity, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

edit:
After some digging, apparently the thread pool's map does not support a vararg -style map, ie map(f, i1, i2, i3,...in) where i1 corresponds to the first argument of f, i2 the second, etc. The exception is thrown because the list I was giving it was being interpreted as the chunk size or some other integer positional argument.

Regardless, neat solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def identity((a,b)): return a, b

print map(identity, zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))

p = ThreadPool(2)

#gives above error:
print p.map(identity, zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
```

#### Output

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. It is using zip _and_ "packing" the argument to the function, not sure of the terminology..thanks!

Comment: @user318904: NOTE: tuple parameter unpacking is removed in Python 3.x http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/